# Whose stack is used when an interrupt handle is running?

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt

I am trying to understand the steps that are followed when an interrupt is taken into account by the processor. Reading from Understanding the Linux Kernel I discovered that first of all the processor needs to determine what is the vector associated with the interrupt, then somehow the address of the ISR is computed. After checking if the interrupt was issued by an authorized source, is checked if there was a change of privilege.

"Checks whether a change of privilege level is taking place—that is, if CPL is different from the selected Segment Descriptor’s DPL. If so, the control unit must start using the stack that is associated with the new privilege level"

My questions are:

1. If an interrupt runs at the expense of the same process
   that was running when the interrupt occurred, why is not using he process' kernel stack?
2. There are different stacks for different privilege levels? I know there is only a kernel stack per process.
3. If so, why the switch of stacks is needed?

Comment: While it would be technically possible to use the less privileged stack, it would mean that information would leak to this lower privilege level. Since security is as much about restricting access to sensible information as about avoiding privilege escalation, keeping the stack would be a very bad idea. And it is much simpler to swap the stack than to try to keep the user stack clean of privileged information by deleting it after every use...

Comment: I didn't say anything about the user stack. I was talking about the kernel stack. Still.. If there are multiple stacks for every privilege level, where are they kept? I know that for every process there are mapped in the resident memory 2 pages (kernel stack + thread info struct). Is this the stack you are talking about? Or there are other stacks? I am still confused :(

Comment: I'm not into the details of the kernel, so I can't really answer your question. But afaik, there is no distinction between privilege levels inside the kernel (one level is for user code, one level is for the kernel, and one level is for hypervisors; the fourth level allowed by X86 CPUs is not used at all). As such, when the kernel deals with less privileged code, it should be user code or virtual machine code, and that is code that should not be trusted to keep a secret. For the details, I can only recommend to read the relevant kernel code yourself. Kernel code is not that hard to read.